# how to do logout redirect to current url

Tags: redirect, login

I'm using custom menu for `login/logout` here below is my code:

```
<?php
   if(is_user_logged_in()) {
      $user = wp_get_current_user();
      echo 'Welcome <strong><a href="http://gopalbonline.com/kolkataonwheels/wp-admin/index.php" >'.$user->user_firstname.'</a></strong>
  | <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a>';
   } else { ?>
      <strong><?php wp_loginout(); ?></strong>
      or <a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/wp-login.php?action=register">     <strong>Register</strong></a>
<?php } ?>
```

but problem is :

1. redirect to 404 page not current page...
2. I want to add user gavatar if he/she logged in

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where are you using this snippet? `get_permalink()` without the post ID will only work inside the Loop.

Comment: A solution for cases get_permalink() does not work can be found at https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_loginout-return-to-current-page

Answer (score 3):

`wp_loginout(get_permalink());` will make hyperlink with "Log out/Log in" text and after log out it will stay in the same page, or it will direct user to log in page.

Answer (score 1):

something like this

```
function my_redirect(){
    $redirect_url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    if(!empty($_REQUEST['redirect_to'])){
        wp_safe_redirect($_REQUEST['redirect_to']);
    } else {
        wp_redirect($redirect_url);
    }
    exit();
}
add_filter('wp_logout','my_redirect');
```

Comment: thanks...
I add your code in function.php but not working. when user logout it should go to index.php

    '<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a>'

    '<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( get_bloginfo('url') ); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a>'

i used both code but not working...some thing missing

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a>
```

Can all be done with WP functions - no custom code required in this case.

You just need to move the code from function.php into the theme and it should work.